# In C++, why use static class function rather than a regular function?

Tags: c++, oop

If the function just does the job that are not bound to any instance of the class, why don't we just use a regular function?

Comment: Access modifiers are not applicable to regular functions. Regular functions can't access static class members.

Comment: Adding to previous comments, also you implicitly introduce a namespace for the function.

Comment: Additionally if you pass to static callback function 'this' pointer you will be able to access private member of that class through the pointer. (Providing that the callback is a static member of that class)

Comment: @S.M. -- regular function can access any public class member, including public static members.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a non-member function, and that's quite common. The primary difference between using a non-member function and a `static` member function is that the non-member function can only access public members of the class (unless it's been marked as a `friend`), and a `static` member function, like all member function, can access all the members.

```
class demo {
public:
    int t;
    static int u;
private:
    int v;
    static int w;
public:
    static void f(const demo&);
};

void demo::f(const demo& d) {
    std::cout << d.t << '\n'; // okay: accessing public member
    std::cout << d.w << '\n'; // okay: member function accessing private member
    std::cout << demo::u << '\n'; // okay: accessing public member
    std::cout << demo::w << '\n'; // okay: member function accessing private member
}

void g(const demo& d) {
    std::cout << d.t << '\n'; // okay: accessing public member
    std::cout << d.w << '\n'; // error: non-member function accessing private member
    std::cout << demo::u << '\n'; // okay: accessing public member
    std::cout << demo::w << '\n'; // error: non-member function accessing private member
}
```